# Json not appear with ajax in cordova

Tags: android, mysql, json, ajax, cordova

Once the problem insert the data cordova to mysql using ajax to host finished now I see the new constraints that display data from the host , when I run localhost data appears by calling json from the local server , but when I call up data from the host data server does not appear when using the same script.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var getData="http://myweb/json.php";
    $.getJSON(getData,function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            var id_code=field.id_code;
            var qrcode=field.qrcode;
            var judul=field.judul;
            var pengarang=field.pengarang;          
            $("#listview").append("<li><a class='item' href='form.html?id_code="+id_code+"&judul="+judul+"&pengarang="+pengarang+"'><h2>"+ judul +"</h2><p>"+ pengarang +"</p></a></li>");
        });
    }); 

});


  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul id="listview" ></ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you added your host server in cordova whitelist?

Comment: thanks @NitishkumarSingh, when I make a android platform plugin cordova-plugin-whitlist has been automatically added, what should I enter the hostname in the config xml ? this my [config.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XIOW0-UhurN05nbFl5ZW04eDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: usually we need to add <access origin="site_url" /> in config.xml, but since <access origin="*" /> is already present in your config.xml. No need to add any new line.

Since it working on localhost, but not for server. There can be Cross-Origin Request issue. Your server is not configured to allow Cross-Origin Request.

Comment: in sever I already added `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` what is added again ?

Comment: can you run your ajax request to server from browser?

Comment: yes if the server using localhost and run from Browser , ajax requests WORK

Comment: can you please provide http response sent by server to your app

Comment: I tried calling the host server online with browser data appears. [this pic http response from browser](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxmOYWlEPiUzVE9oQU5rMmJpanM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please search online how to check http response for android app, android SDK setup itself provides the tool

Comment: I know to overcome my problem , it turns out there at the time of calling `field` on json , when I replace with `element` the problem is resolved ,